# Проксирование с nginx location даёт ошибку 404

Tags: nginx, proxy

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
    # ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Если конектиться на порт 8060, сокет сервер работает. А через nginx не могу настроить проксирование

Подключаюсь

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://domain.com/ws");
```

Ошибка

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://domain.com/ws' failed:
  Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
```

Если добавить последний слэш

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://domain.com/ws/");

WebSocket connection to 'ws://domain.com/ws/' failed:
  Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Comment: Ваш сокет-сервер настроен на обработку урла `/ws/`? Что-то мне подсказывает, что он умеет обрабатывать только `/`, а вы пытаетесь `/ws/` открывать, на что он закономерно отвечает 404

Comment: так в location указываю /ws/

Comment: Ну да, именно поэтому этот `/ws/` передаётся дальше сокет-серверу на порт 8060, а тот не умеет обрабатывать `/ws/` и отдаёт ошибку 404. Скорее всего.

Comment: Да, location /ws
совсем не думал что aiohttp не так обрабатывает урлы как джанго, упустил этот момент

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста отдельно, чтобы отметить решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы пишете

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
    # ...
}
```

nginx отправляет сокет-серверу (вашему aiohttp, который висит на порту 8060) запрос вида `ws://localhost:8060/ws/` — то есть сохраняет ту ссылку, которую отправил браузер. Ваш сокет-сервер должен уметь обработать именно такую ссылку, в противном случае он может ответить 404 — видимо, мой внутренний телепат угадал, что происходит именно это.

Вы можете выкинуть кусок `/ws/` из ссылки, прописав такую настройку:

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8060/;
    # ...
}
```

То есть просто добавить слэш в конце `proxy_pass`. В таком случае nginx не передаёт оригинальную ссылку как есть, а откусывает прописанный в `location` кусок, и запрос вида `ws://domain.com/ws/` будет перенаправлен на `ws://localhost:8060/` — и это скорее всего сокет-сервер сможет обработать без дополнительных изменений в нём.

Учтите, что в последнем примере запрос вида `ws://domain.com/ws/чтототам/` будет перенаправлен на `ws://localhost:8060/чтототам/` — если у вас есть такие ссылки, то по-моему лучше так не делать во избежание путаницы и лучше просто научить aiohttp распознавать ссылку `/ws/`.

Подробнее о поведении `proxy_pass` можно почитать в [документации nginx](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).